# Problems with html in JToggleButton

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

My case is simple: I am using html formatting for jtogglebutton text, but when any button is selected, it's text simply disappears:

[image: gui problem]

This bug exists only for text like `<html><b>sss</b> fff</html>`, but not like `"any usual text"`
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: works fine for me.what is the os and look and feel ?

Comment: @FastSnail windows 7

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm in progress @AndrewTompson

Comment: the bug turned out to be somewhere deep inside our company's specific look and feel, it would take a lot time to reproduce...